# How do I get the Caucus badge?

Tags: support, badges, election

I've visited the [election](http://www.stackoverflow.com/election) page and looked at some of the nominations. Do I need to wait until nominations end before the badge is awarded? I clicked on the badge and I saw plenty of users being awarded it so I'm guessing I don't have to wait until nominations end.

Is this a bug or is there something special I need to do to be awarded this badge?

Comment: It may be that you only get the Caucus badge if you're eligible to vote in the election. Then you'd need 19 rep more, possibly have to revisit the election page after that.

Comment: I have 131 reputation on the main SO site. I assume it's your SO rep that counts and not your meta rep?

Comment: You need 150 rep to vote in the election, iirc.

Comment: Ah, but "If you can’t vote, you can at least make your voice heard. This is a bronze badge." [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/?cb=1) strongly suggests that Caucus would be attainable even before you have the right to vote.

Comment: Sorry I just assumed you meant you were on about my meta rep as 106 + 19 would be a nice round 125

Comment: Heh, nice. Identical distance to a milestone in SO and MSO ;) But as per the quote in my previous comment, methinks you should get it even when you can't yet vote. Try doing something on the election page, upvote a comment or so.

Comment: I up voted multiple comments and still no badge

Comment: Visit Chechnya.

Comment: I finally got over 150 rep and got the Caucus badge :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the people being awarded the Caucus badge currently they all have a rep of at least 150 so I'm guessing having 150 rep or more must be a prerequisite for the Caucus badge. They should either inform users of this or make s change so all users can get this badge.

Comment: Possible, you need 150 to vote.

Comment: Taken from the `title` attribute of the badge: "bronze badge: Visited an election during any phase of an active election and have enough reputation to cast a vote"

Comment: Just noticed that, it didn't say that yesterday.
Looks like my question made a difference :)

Answer (score 9):

This badge is tied to the ability to vote - you do in fact need to have 150 reputation.  We'll make sure this clear in the description of the badge.  If you don't have 150 reputation you're always encouraged to participate so that you can make your vote count.

Answer (score 4):

It usually takes a few minutes until you get a badge. Be patient ;)

Comment: Well, there are Caucus badges awarded every five minutes right now. I don't see PriestVallon in there, and there's been quite a few badge runs since then.

Comment: patience what's that. :)

Comment: @Mat: Right, good point, I just noticed that myself. Usually it shouldn't take *this* long. Maybe something went wrong or there is another requirement after all? E.g. visit length or which site you came from.

Comment: Still no sign of the badge!

Answer (score 2):

From the *updated* [list of badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

#### Caucus

- bronze; awarded multiple times; same family as Constituent (silver)
- Visit an election page while an election is in progress
- You must have the minimum reputation required to be able to vote in the election
- You get the badge once per election, as long as you visit the election page while an election phase (nomination, primary or final) is in progress
- Introduced [during the 2012 Stack Overflow moderator election](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/)

Unless the moderators are incorrect, all you need to do is visit the election page while an election (nomination, primary, or final) is in progress. :)